Как получить из eventData.pointerDrag конкретный класс? А также как сократить ифы и элсы?
У меня есть два класса: ItemAmmunition и ItemConsumables. Они оба работают +- одинаково, однако их главное отличие - ItemAmmunition может помещаться в MainCell и AmmunitionCell, а ItemConsumables только в MainCell. И отсюда начинаются все проблемы!
Нерабочий код в MainCell-е.
public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    var a = eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<ItemConsumables>();
    if (eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<ItemConsumables>() != null)
        a = eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<ItemConsumables>();
    else
        a = eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<ItemAmmunition>();

    if (CheckCellFree(this, a.size))
    {
        a.prevMainCell = this;

        a.SetPosition(a.gameObject, this, null);
        CellOccupation(this, false, dragItem.size);
    }
    else
    {
        dragItem.SetPosition(dragItem.gameObject, dragItem.prevMainCell, null);
        CellOccupation(dragItem.prevMainCell, false, dragItem.size);
    }
} 

Я не могу даже нормально узнать, что там содержится, и написать это! Если я буду делать этот код так (Первый, но уже исправленный мною код.):
public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
{

    if (eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<ItemConsumables>() != null)
    {
        var a = eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<ItemConsumables>();
        if (CheckCellFree(this, a.size))
        {
            a.prevMainCell = this;

            a.SetPosition(a.gameObject, this, null);
            CellOccupation(this, false, a.size);
        }
        else
        {
            dragItem.SetPosition(a.gameObject, a.prevMainCell, null);
            CellOccupation(a.prevMainCell, false, a.size);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var a = eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<ItemAmmunition>();
        if (CheckCellFree(this, a.size))
        {
            a.prevMainCell = this;

            a.SetPosition(a.gameObject, this, null);
            CellOccupation(this, false, a.size);
        }
        else
        {
            dragItem.SetPosition(a.gameObject, a.prevMainCell, null);
            CellOccupation(a.prevMainCell, false, a.size);
        }
    }
}

То выходит вообще длинно! Я бьюсь с этим уже очень долго. Как сокращать эти if-else-ы, и как вообще присваивать вот такие переменные? Не хочется выдумывать велосипеды.

Не до конца понял, про какой именно из трех кусков кода вопрос? Что надо оптимизировать?

Это мой первый вопрос, сорри. Вообще по сути вопрос про первый кусок. Второй - это пример моей кривой реализации. Третий - пример, где ещё мне мешают if-ы. В первом куске нужно как-то в одну переменную запихнуть два класса, чтобы потом работать именно с одной переменной (Либо сделать что-то вроде краткого if-а, чтобы не занимать много кода и сразу работать с нужным классом.

Я исправил несколько деталей и удалил третью часть кода. Надеюсь, что так будет проще и понятнее.

Зачем заголовки методов поудаляли? Стало ещё непонятнее.

Так вы же правку добавили без них)))0) Я думал, удалить надо, пхах. Я же говорю, пока разбираюсь с этим сайтом вообще) Сейчас добавлю...

Я в правке перенес их на новую строку, потому что они не отображались. Ответ готов.

Как я понял, речь про второй кусочек кода. Вам надо почитать про обобщения (generic).
Но для того чтобы обобщить, нужно чтобы классы ItemConsumables и ItemAmmunition имели общего наследника или реализовывали общий интерфейс, имеющий публичные члены, которые вам требуются.
Так как классов не вижу, а типы по коду не понять, не смогу описать интерфейс точно. Думаю, сможете дополнить самостоятельно.
public interface IItem
{
    public ... prevMainCell;
    public ... SetPosition(...);
    public ... gameObject;
    public ... size;
}

Далее указать, что классы реализуют этот интерфейс
public class ItemConsumables : MonoBehavior, IItem
{
    // ...
}

public class ItemAmmunition : MonoBehavior, IItem
{
    // ...
}

Получится как-то так
public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    IItem a = eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<ItemConsumables>();
    if (a == null)
        a = eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<ItemAmmunition>();

    if (CheckCellFree(this, a.size))
    {
        a.prevMainCell = this;

        a.SetPosition(a.gameObject, this, null);
        CellOccupation(this, false, dragItem.size);
    }
    else
    {
        dragItem.SetPosition(dragItem.gameObject, dragItem.prevMainCell, null);
        CellOccupation(dragItem.prevMainCell, false, dragItem.size);
    }
} 


Огромное спасибо) Да, у меня был класс-родитель, и через него получилось выйти на его "детей", я просто не знал, что так можно. Благодарю))
